# OAuth Google Analytics Client API javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-client

I'm trying to connect the Google client API to display Google Analytics Data on my website.

So i use this tutorial to try to connect the client API :
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

i followed all the instructions, i made a OAuth Client on Google Developper Console.

[image]

here my code  :

```
<button id="authorize-button">Authorize</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXX';

      var apiKey = 'XXXXXXX';

      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Step 2: Reference the API key
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {

        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
      function makeApiCall() {

        // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function() {
          // Step 5: Assemble the API request
          var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
          });
          // Step 6: Execute the API request

          request.then(function(resp) {
            var heading = document.createElement('h4');
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = resp.result.image.url;
            heading.appendChild(image);
            heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.result.displayName));

            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);
          }, function(reason) {
            console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
    // Step 1: Load JavaScript client library
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

but it dont work, and i have no idea of what is the problem, i get this error  :

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
immediate=false
response_type=token
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay509775948
state=658721539|0.1255556678
origin=http://localhost
include_granted_scopes=true
client_id='MY SECRED KEY'
authuser=0
That’s all we know.
```

[image]

If anyone have a solution, it should be very nice ;)
thanks in advance.

Comment: *no need to show us the API key*

Comment: thank you , I forgot to hide the api key

Comment: In the developer console, consent screen make sure you added email address and product name.  Also looks like the scope you are using is the google+ scope which is no the Google analytics scope you will have to change that but its not related to the client error message.

Comment: Also remember this is Oauth2 you are using its going to require authentication. so if another user comes to your site its not going to display your Google analytics data its going to display theirs.

Answer (score 0):

i was in the wrong way, to display content from GAI , i need to use the Hello analytics tutorial, with PHP code.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api?hl=fr#auth

apparently the documentation is outdated.

thanks...

Comment: The documentation has been updated: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/